# How to format nodes/structs within tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have made the following [Eisenhower square (or matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_management#The_Eisenhower_Method) inspired by this [fantastic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447440/223558):

[image: Eisonhower square]

I would like mine to be much more space-efficient: smaller text size/check boxes, thinner borders, no space/margin/gutter between squares, no horizontal lines within squares, etc.
Text on left is a good approximation of the max. size check list item text should be.

But after extensive tinkering, I am still unable to change the following properties:

1. Borders

   - Make borders ultra-thin (1 px would suffice)
2. Checklist items/boxes

   - Remove horizontal lines
   - Make check `\Box` for each checklist item smaller and/or scale with text
   - Make items tighter/closer together vertically?
3. `label` text

   - Center-aligned on left/top edge of individual squares

Below is my document:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[english]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning, fit, backgrounds}

...

% \eisenbox: for making each box of an Eisenhower square
\newcommand{\eisenbox}[6][] {
    \node [rectangle split,rectangle split parts={#6}, fill=white,
    text width=5.25cm,align=left,text=#2,draw,sharp corners,draw=#2,
    #1]
    (multi-#3)
    {\strut$\Box$\nodepart{two}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{three}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{four}\strut$\Box$
    \nodepart{five}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{six}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{seven}\strut$\Box$
    \nodepart{eight}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{nine}\strut$\Box$\nodepart{ten}\strut$\Box$};
    \node[left=1pt of multi-#3.south west,anchor=south west,rotate=90,text=black] 
    (label-#3) {#5};
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[fit=(multi-#3),fill=#2,sharp corners,
        label={[text=#2,anchor=south west,font=\bfseries]above left:#4}] (fit-#3){};
    \end{scope}
}

% \eisensquare: creates a fancy Eisenhower square
\newcommand{\eisensquare}[1] {
    \eisenbox{black}{tl}{\footnotesize Urgent}{\footnotesize Important}{#1}
    \eisenbox[right=0.2cm of multi-tl]{black}{tr}{\footnotesize Not Urgent}{}{#1}
    \eisenbox[below=0.2cm of multi-tl]{black}{bl}{}{\footnotesize Not Important}{#1}
    \eisenbox[right=0.2cm of multi-bl]{black}{br}{}{}{#1}
}

...

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter

    \maketitle
    ...

    \mainmatter

    ...
    \subfile{./folder/subfile.tex}

    \backmatter

\end{document}
```

`subfile.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

    \begin{document}

    ...
    
    \paragraph{Foo}\mbox{}\\    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
            \eisensquare{7}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
    ...

\end{document}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  `tikz` ignores/throws an error wherever I place the `width`, `line width`, etc. anywhere in the `\node [options]` within `\eisenbox`.

I am completely new to `pgf`/`tikz`, so any insights would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1
------------

As per [gernot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot) [exemplary answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562170/223558) I've just about got it.  All that remains is modification for variable number of items per 'quadrant'.  I would normally never be so particular, were it not for the fact that I will be using this every day for a very long time.

How would one go about making blank/empty lines for when lines remaining > number of items?

`main.tex`

```
\newcommand\eisenlabel[1]{{\footnotesize\sffamily#1}}

% arguments: 1st is total # lines, 2nd is # items
\newcommand{\eisenbox}[2]{\fbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \multido{}{#1}{%
                \makebox[0.44\textwidth][l]{$\square$} %adding \\ here makes errors, but I believe its absence is FUBARing the table
            }
        \end{tabular}%
}}

% first argument: max lines, then items per quadrant starting with urgent+important
% could do this without 1st arg by determining largest value
% but not familiar enough with this so we'll just supply it manually (for now)
\newcommand{\eisensquare}[5] {%
    \fboxrule=0.1ex% <<< adjust line width
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{0.3em}}c@{\hspace{-\fboxrule}}c@{}} % <<< adjust distance between rotated labels and box
        & \eisenlabel{urgent} & \eisenlabel{not urgent} \\
        \turnbox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\eisenlabel{important}}}
        & \eisenbox{#1}{#2} & \eisenbox{#1}{#3} \\[-\fboxrule] 
        \turnbox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\eisenlabel{not important}}}
        & \eisenbox{#1}{#4} & \eisenbox{#1}{#5}
    \end{tabular}%
}
```

`subfile.tex`

```
\(\eisensquare{5}{3}{4}{5}{3}\)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexibel solution. Since `\multido` doesn't work well in a `tabular`, I used even more basic commands. The top-level command is

```
\eisensquare{height of single box}{width of single box}{top left}{top right}{bottom left}{bottom right}
```

`height` and `width` can be absolute dimensions or multiples of lengths like `\baselineskip` (height of a line) or `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,rotating,multido}
% \eisenlabel{width}{label}
\newcommand\eisenlabel[2]{\makebox[#1]{\footnotesize\sffamily#2}}
% \veisenlabel{height}{label}
\newcommand\veisenlabel[2]{\turnbox{90}{\eisenlabel{#1}{#2}}\ }
% \eisenbox{height}{width}{number of items}
\newcommand\eisenbox[3]{\fbox{%
  \vbox to #1{%
    \multido{}{#3}{\hbox to #2{$\square$\hfill}}%
    \vfill  
  }%
}}
% \eisensquare{height of single box}{width of single box}{top left}{top right}{bottom left}{bottom right}
\newcommand\eisensquare[6]{{%
  \fboxrule=0.1ex%
  \vbox{%
    \hbox{\ \eisenlabel{#2}{urgent}\ \eisenlabel{#2}{not urgent}}%
    \hbox{\veisenlabel{#1}{important}\eisenbox{#1}{#2}{#3}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\eisenbox{#1}{#2}{#4}}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \hbox{\veisenlabel{#1}{not important}\eisenbox{#1}{#2}{#5}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\eisenbox{#1}{#2}{#6}}%
}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\eisensquare{5\baselineskip}{0.4\textwidth}{3}{4}{5}{3}

\noindent
\eisensquare{2cm}{5cm}{3}{4}{5}{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah gernot I may just have to name my firstborn after you for all the brilliant help you have provided.  Worked like a charm and was exactly what was needed

Comment: @SKNB If needed: I have also a second name.

Answer (score 1):

Tikz is a wonderful package, but for such a simple design I suggest to use tabulars. It may be more apparent where to modify the appearance.

[image]

I suggest to use `em` or `ex` as length units, as they change with the font size. In the code, I have marked the places where to adjust the width of the boxes, the line width, and the distance of the vertical labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,rotating}
\newcommand\eisenlabel[1]{{\footnotesize\sffamily#1}}
\newcommand\eisenline{\makebox[0.44\textwidth][l]{$\square$}}% <<< adjust width of boxes
\newcommand\eisenbox{\fbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline\\
    \eisenline
  \end{tabular}%
}}
\newcommand\eisensquare{{%
  \fboxrule=0.1ex% <<< adjust line width
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{0.3em}}c@{\hspace{-\fboxrule}}c@{}} % <<< adjust distance between rotated labels and box
    & \eisenlabel{urgent} & \eisenlabel{not urgent} \\
  \turnbox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\eisenlabel{important}}}
    & \eisenbox & \eisenbox \\[-\fboxrule] 
  \turnbox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\eisenlabel{not important}}}
    & \eisenbox & \eisenbox
  \end{tabular}%
}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\eisensquare
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is *way* easier than tikz, excellent suggestion!  This is exactly what I needed.  But supposing the quadrants could have differing numbers of items?  So all quadrants the same size, but with varying numbers of check boxes (with empty lines for lines > number of items).  I'll append what I have so far to my answer, but I can't get it to work.